# Given a bag of red/blue balls how many times to sample with replacement to get a certain confidence of the distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, confidence-interval, statistical-power

Thanks in advance for the help and I apologize if any of the terminology I use is incorrect; I'm not the best statistician.

This is actually somewhat of a two part question.

Suppose that I have a bag that is filled with red and blue balls.  I have no idea how many balls are in the bag, but I want to know the distribution of red and blue balls.  To determine this, I can sample with replacement as many times as I want.

Is it possible to calculate the number of times that I must sample in order to determine the distribution of red and blue balls with a certain confidence (despite not knowing how many balls are in the bag)?  If so, lets say that the level of confidence that I want is $x$.

Given that it is possible to determine the distribution of red and blue balls with confidence $x$ suppose the probability that I observed I would draw a red ball is $r$.  Is it correct to say then out of say 10 ball draws the probability of not drawing a red ball is $x(1 - r)^{10}$ or is correct to say that I am $x$ percent confident that the probability that I won't draw a red ball is $(1 - r)^{10}$?

Edit:
To put what I'm asking in more concrete terms, what I have is a process that that will run forever.  At every uniform discrete time step either result 0 or result 1 will occur (the result is independent of time and past behavior of the process; I just dont know the probability of either occurring, hence my need to observe the system and determine some kind of confidence value).  Given an interval of $t$ steps I want to be able to say that result 0 will not happen more than $a$ times with confidence $x$.  The red/ball question I've given above was my attempt to simplify my question without going into the specifics of what I am actually trying to do.

Comment: Your edit appears to pose a different question: although originally you seem to want a *confidence interval* for the proportions of balls, the edit seems to ask for *prediction intervals* about a sequence of future steps.  Which of these questions are you trying to ask?  (Maybe you *ought* to go into some of the specifics, since it looks like some crucial information might have been lost in the simplification.)

Comment: I want a confidence interval for the distribution of balls.  Using this distribution, I want to be able to make predictions about what may happen if I draw a specific number of balls.  The ball example that I gave is my attempt at designing an approach for solving the problem I gave in my edit.

Comment: Your question seems to be about [binomial proportion confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) (e.g. see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+proportion+confidence)). I am not sure you can calculate the required number of trials a priori, particularly in the case of "sparse" blue (or red). Typically you would want to draw *at least* until you see one of each color, prior to estimating a confidence interval. (And in general, the smaller the sample, the more your prior will influence the results.)